# In PyCharm, is it possible to deploy automatically to remote host after git merge?

Tags: python, git, pycharm, git-merge, git-deploy

I'm using the PyCharm Professional version, and I write the project code on a Windows 10 laptop (noted as `A`), and use the `Deployment` tool in PyCharm to sync the code with the remote client with Ubuntu (nated as `B`). And at the same time, the project also contains some code from the third party (e.g., the GitHub repositories). Suppose the project on `A` has the following directory structure:

```
E:/project/mycode/hello.py
E:/project/third_party/pytorch/
E:/project/.idea
```

and the mirror project code on `B` is:

```
/media/ubuntu/Code/project/mycode/hello.py
/media/ubuntu/Code/project/third_party/pytorch/
```

When I modified the `hello.py` on `A`, the PyCharm will automatically copy it into the corresponding position on `B` (i.e., `/media/ubuntu/Code/project/mycode/hello.py`).

Now, I update the `pytorch` on `A` with

```
cd E:/project/third_party/pytorch/
git pull origin master
```

Then, some files of `pytorch` on `A` will be updated. My question is, is it possible for PyCharm that those latest modified  files in `pytorch` can automatically deploy to the corresponding position on `B` without manually sync the whole files in `pytorch` using PyCharm?

When using the `Deployment` tool in PyCharm, it will copy all those files into the remote client `B`, but  in fact only those latest modified files need to be copied.